# HTA script won't work if folder name contains a space

Tags: javascript, html, hta

I'm looking for some help as to why my simple HTA application won't work if a folder in the file path has a space in its name.

My HTA has a simple button to launch a text file within a sub folder.

The HTA has a script which finds the root folder of the HTA file.

If the location of my HTA file is the path below the button works:

```
c:\Users\%MyUser%\Desktop\htatest2
```

If the folder name is changed to "hta test2" the button doesn't work.

```
c:\Users\%MyUser%\Desktop\hta test2
```

here is my code below.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Application Executer</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID="oMyApp" 
        APPLICATIONNAME="Application Executer" 
        BORDER="no"
        CAPTION="no"
        SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
        SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
        SYSMENU="yes"
        SCROLL="no"
        WINDOWSTATE="normal">

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            var rootdir = shell.currentDirectory;

            function RunFile() {
                WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                WshShell.Run(rootdir+"/txt/text.txt", 1, false);
            }
        </script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Run Notepad" onclick="RunFile();" class="button" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Run` executes its first argument as it was written to command line. You've to include double quotes in the argument. Use single quotes for the concatenation to prevent conflicting quotes, like so:

```
WshShell.Run('"' + rootdir + '/txt/text.txt' + '"', 1, false);
```

Comment: Hi Teemu, Thanks for the help, this solution has worked.